# Executing a file not a project

Tags: php, ide, editor

I use Aptana Studio for my PHP projects. I have not learned it but just used with what I was able to do in it. Many features I still don't know how to use in it.

At present, I have a HTML form and I want to write a .php script for the SEND button that it has. It is a submission script for the contact form.

I want a simple PHP IDE with which I can execute a single PHP file or work with at least two or three files easily, without much mess.

Please suggest a simple alternative to Aptana.

Comment: Where is the problem with Aptana/Eclipse? You don't have to use all its features and a project is basically just a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[netbeans for PHP](http://netbeans.org/features/php/)**, it is the best php editor ever made with lot and lots of functionality. 
 But **you will have to spend some time with it**. This case is with every editor that you choose to code in. So spent some time with netbeans and I bet you will be amazed by it's feature set.


atleast give it a try.

and if you don't want the code completion then [notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) is a good choice, [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) is also a good option

Comment: NetBeans is a resource hog. It runs too slow on a machine with 1 GB RAM.